# No way to Get-Item in powershell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface, aws-cli

So I've tried a few things now, one of which is AWS.Tools.DynamoDBv2 and nothing seems to work.

AWS CLI works in powershell to an extent, for example, the command "aws ec2 describe-instances..." works. However, "aws dynamodb get-item --table-name  --key "{"primary-key":{"S":"myitem"}}" does not.

It returns the error stating that "{"primary-key":{"S":"myitem"}}" is an unknown option.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

aws dynamodb get-item --table-name  --key "{"primarykey":{"S":"myitem"}}

```
aws : 
At line:1 char:1
+ aws dynamodb get-item --table-name <mytable> --key "{ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
Unknown options: primary-key:{S:myitem}}
```

Edit:
Thanks for the help! This was really grinding my gears! As Abraham Zinala suggested, single quotes were necessary around the whole key object. Also, backslashes inside were necessary too:

```
--key '{\"primarykey\":{\"S\":\"myitem\"}}'
```

Comment: which version of aws cli do you use?

Comment: Basing this off just PowerShell logic, you should have to enclose the `--key` argument with single quotes: `aws dynamodb get-item --table-name --key '{"primarykey":{"S":"myitem"}}'`.

Comment: @petrch I'm using AWS Tools for Poweshell version 4.1.204

Comment: @Abraham Zinala thanks! the single quotes were definitely necessary!

Comment: Please provide the answer as a 'self-answer' or even better, wait for @AbrahamZinala to provide the above as an answer; that way the question isn't left as 'unanswered'. Welcome to Stack Overflow 

Answer (score 1):

As @AbrahamZinala suggested, single quotes were necessary around the whole key object. Also, backslashes inside were necessary too:

```
--key '{\"primarykey\":{\"S\":\"myitem\"}}'
```

Also, for what it's worth, if using string interpolation, it would have to look like this:

```
--key '{\`"$primarykey\`":{\`"S\`":\`"$myitem\`"}}'
```